# what is a cross processor speed unit?

Tags: cpu, cpu-usage, processor, stress-testing, cpu-speed

I'm doing stress test against some application for CPU usage but i don't know which hardware it is going to be deployed, I'm looking for some sort of cross processor unit to give an exact information about CPU usage on any kind of CPU to my client.
for example if the application use 25% of CPU-1, how much it's going to need in CPU-2 or CPU-3?
I'm thinking of FLOPS. is it trusty or do i have any alternatives?
Can i calculate FLOPS easily for any CPU?
Or is there any other solution for my problem?

Comment: you can calculate flops easily http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLOPS

Comment: FLOPS, or floating point operations is useful if your application is floating point intensive.  If your app doesn't use floating point (e.g. a web server) the FLOPS rating is irrelevant.

Comment: actually it is a webserver and an application inside, so what can i use instead?